# Extracting data from two different functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out the number of stores which were NOT operating throughout 2015. I have used the following two formulas:

1) `io15 = iowa[(iowa.year == 2015) & (iowa.month >= 1) & (iowa.month <= 12)]`
This is to find out the number of stores open throughout 2015

2) `tio15 = iowa[(iowa.year == 2015)]`
This contains the total list of all stores.

Common sense should be to subtract `io15` from `tio15`. I'm trying to use the below formula but it's not working:

```
def diff(tio15,io15):
    c = set(tio15).union(set(io15))
    d = set(tio15).intersection(set(io15))
    return list(c - d)
```

Please help

Comment: Could you provide some example of the data set or explain what do you mean by not working? If I do diff([1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4]) for example it gives [0,4], which sounds like what you want. Though I am not sure why you are doing union and intersection. Isn't tio15 a subset of io15?

Comment: What is the incorrect output you *are* getting?  This function looks like it should return a list of the stores open for only part of 2015.

Comment: I tried diff(tio15,io15) but its not working. Its giving me []

Comment: @Prune my formula is not giving me any output. I find this strange as both the individual function appear to give me proper results in jupyter notebook. I just wanted the difference between the two functions.

Comment: @Miriam my formula is not giving me any result. The functions mentioned 1 & 2 above both appear to be working fine. I just need to extract the list of stores mentioned in tio15 and NOT mentioned in io15

Comment: A Python function *always* returns a result.  Even if you don't explicitly return something, the run-time system will return **None**.  Please supply a  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, what are the values of the two sets *before* you do the difference?  Everything you state about the results implies that they're equal sets, but you seem to have done no debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If tio15 is the list of all stores, then unioning it with io15 is a NO-OP. Because by definition io15 should be a subset of tio15.

What you want is, `set(tio15) - set(io15)`, i.e., items those are in tio15 but not in io15.

Comment: Hi i used set(tio15) - set(io15) but the result I'm getting is set(). Its not giving me any values